# How can I modify these 2 codes to encrypt and decrypt entire files of text?

Tags: python-3.x

The instruction says that we should modify the scripts of project 1 and 2 to encrypt and decrypt entire files of a text. Here are the projects that I coded.

Project 1

```
message = input("Enter a message: ")
dValue = int(input("Enter distance value: "))
code = ""

for ch in message:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue + dValue

    code += chr(cipherValue)
print()
print(code)
```

Project 2

```
coded_text = input("Enter a coded text: ")
dValue = int(input("Enter distance value: "))
code = ""

for ch in coded_text:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue - dValue

    code += chr(cipherValue)
print()
print(code)
```

First, I declared the variables for input and I don't know what to do after that. Here is an example of the program interface.

```
Enter the input file name: encrypted.txt
Enter the output file name: a
Enter the distance value: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

To open a file and read its content, you can use the following code:

```
with open(FILE_PATH) as file:
    print(f.read())
```

To write to a file:

```
with open(FILE_PATH,"w") as file:
    file.write(code)
```

Using the ‘with’ statement is good because it closes the file after it has been used.

To implement it in your code(Project 1):

```
file_path_input = input("Enter the input file path: ")
file_path_output = input("Enter the output file path: ")
dValue = int(input("Enter distance value: "))
code = ""

#Read the text from the file
with open(file_path_input) as file1:
    text = file1.read()

for ch in text:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue + dValue

    code += chr(cipherValue)

print()
print(code)

#Write the code to another file
with open(file_path_output,"w") as file2:
    file2.write(code)
```

You can do the same for the project 2.